# How would you say: [not] trespassing on someone else's field of expertise

Tags: phrase-requests

There is a manager in our company that he thinks that I am trying to do some task that he is the one that should be doing not me.
I am trying to decline his assumptions but my attempts sound wrong:

- I am not crossing your specialty ...
- I am not trespassing your field of specialty ...

Comment: MOD NOTE: Answers go in the answer box, not the comment box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common colloquialism would be "[treading on your toes](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tread+on+toes)" (though Xanne's comment works too).

You could also say "I know this is your area, but..."

"Crossing your specialty" sounds odd to [this] native English speaker, and "trespassing", while quite a nice way of putting it, would work better with a preposition ("trespassing in" or "trespassing on").

Comment: I surfed the net for "treading on your toes" , it brought an interesting expression (overstepping boundaries) but it sounds more generic. I like yours better.